# Get the prev / next page links only (not title, <a> etc)

Tags: links

I currently use the following method to get a prev / next blog page link:

```
<?php previous_post_link( '%link', '%title' ); ?>
```

However this includes the outer element, name etc, I want just the link e.g. `http://domain.com/blog/page/2`

Is there a function that I'm not seeing to suit my requirements?

**Clarification**

- This is for the next blog page (not blog post)
- I only want the link, not the anchor element

Many thanks

Answer (score 19):

**Short answer:** `get_previous_posts_page_link` is the function you want:

```
<?php if($url = get_previous_posts_page_link()): ?>
  do stuff with $url
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Longer answer:** follow the code.

`previous_posts_link` calls `get_previous_posts_link`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Display the previous posts page link.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 * @uses get_previous_posts_link()
 *
 * @param string $label Optional. Previous page link text.
 */
function previous_posts_link( $label = null ) {
    echo get_previous_posts_link( $label );
}
```

`get_previous_posts_link` calls `previous_posts` to fetch the link URI itself.

```
<?php
/**
 * Return the previous posts page link.
 *
 * @since 2.7.0
 *
 * @param string $label Optional. Previous page link text.
 * @return string|null
 */
function get_previous_posts_link( $label = null ) {
    global $paged;

    if ( null === $label )
        $label = __( '&laquo; Previous Page' );

    if ( !is_single() && $paged > 1 ) {
        $attr = apply_filters( 'previous_posts_link_attributes', '' );
        return '<a href="' . previous_posts( false ) . "\" $attr>". preg_replace( '/&([^#])(?![a-z]{1,8};)/i', '&#038;$1', $label ) .'</a>';
    }
}
```

`previous_posts` is just a little wrapper around the function you're looking for: `get_previous_posts_page_link`

```
<?php
/**
 * Display or return the previous posts page link.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 *
 * @param boolean $echo Optional. Echo or return;
 */
function previous_posts( $echo = true ) {
    $output = esc_url( get_previous_posts_page_link() );

    if ( $echo )
        echo $output;
    else
        return $output;
}
```

The function we want:

```
<?php
/**
 * Retrieve previous posts page link.
 *
 * Will only return string, if not on a single page or post.
 *
 * Backported to 2.0.10 from 2.1.3.
 *
 * @since 2.0.10
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
function get_previous_posts_page_link() {
    global $paged;

    if ( !is_single() ) {
        $nextpage = intval($paged) - 1;
        if ( $nextpage < 1 )
            $nextpage = 1;
        return get_pagenum_link($nextpage);
    }
}
```

I included all of that to illustrate how you can go about finding answers by looking through the core.  Tools like [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) can help you get started:

```
shell$ cd /path/to/your/wordpress/install
shell$ ack "function previous_posts_link"
```

In general, the WordPress is pretty good at making sure a function only does one thing.  Tracing from broader functions (ala `previous_posts_link` and other template tags) back to more basic functions is usually a good way to learn some cool stuff and find your answer.

Comment: Wow, very informative answer, and does the job 5 years on, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php get_previous_posts_link(); ?>
```

Obviously you store this in an array, like

```
<?php $prev = get_previous_posts_link(); ?>
```

Comment: Is there a way to just get the link, and not the `<a href=""></a>` element?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any other elements then you can add the following code to your theme's page template instead. You links will then be assigned to $prevID and $nextID which you can do what you like with.

```
<?php
$pagelist = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order&sort_order=asc');
$pages = array();
foreach ($pagelist as $page) {
$pages[] += $page->ID;
}

$current = array_search($post->ID, $pages);
$prevID = $pages[$current-1];
$nextID = $pages[$current+1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @liam-jay, but only getting one of the posts

```
$prev_post = get_previous_post();
empty($prev_post) or $link = $prev_post->guid;
```

I think this should work fine, untested though.

Comment: A GUID is not a link. It looks like one but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

this is working:

```
    <?php
    $next_post_url = get_permalink( get_adjacent_post(false,'',false)->ID );
    $previous_post_url = get_permalink( get_adjacent_post(false,'',true)->ID );        
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity. [previous_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/previous_posts/) and [next_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_posts/) will do just that.

```
echo previous_posts( 0, false );
```

```
echo next_posts( 0, false );
```