# how to get pagination link url?

Tags: pagination

how can I get a pagination link URL instead of a made-up anchor link?
currently, I used

```
<?php next_posts_link(); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
```

for pagination but it returns `a`, I want to know is there any way to get just the next/prev URL?

Comment: Please have look if this helps: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57831/get-the-prev-next-page-links-only-not-title-a-etc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you check out the source, they're both wrappers around `*_posts()`, which in turn are wrappers for `get_*_posts_page_link()` (where the wildcard indicates either `next` or `previous`).

For example, [`next_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_posts/) will echo or return the escaped URL, depending on the first argument:

```
$escaped_url = next_posts( false /* Don't echo */ ); 
next_posts(); // Prints escaped URL
```

Otherwise you can get the raw URL with [`get_next_posts_page_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_next_posts_page_link/) and do with it as you wish:

```
 $raw_url = get_next_posts_page_link();

 wp_redirect( $raw_url );

 // or...
 echo esc_url( $raw_url );
```

Answer (score -2):

There are [`get_previous_posts_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_posts_link) and [`get_next_posts_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_posts_link), they should do what you want.

Comment: as doc for these 2 functions mentioned, they return previous functions(next_posts_link, previous_posts_link) instead of echoing them, I'm trying to get just the url, like: `http://example.com/page/2`

Comment: The Codex page for [`next_posts_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) tells to use these functions when you need the value returned instead of outputted.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but `get_*_posts_page_link()` did the trick